# Static Dictionary with search value in URL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am creating a Online Dictionary only a Static Page with a few PHP JS codes nothing more, I know maybe that is possible or easier with a CMS, but I try to do it as Static Page.

I already create the home  with the search form and the DB connection thats fine and everything works. Now I need an advice how to realize  the following stuffs (  no code nothing only an idea and advice):

#### What I have:

I have a home page with form and DB connection and

I have admin page where I can enter a word or sentence which sends it to the db 
my DB look like:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id | Language A   | Language B    |  Url       |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1  |              |               |            |
--------------------------------------------------
| 2  |              |               |            |
--------------------------------------------------
```

I can add Language A and B

#### What I would like to get:

But URL in DB should be generate automaticly so if there is a ü ä ö etc in a word. if it is a sentence it should concatenate the words like hallo+world

Every word should have his own page so if you search for "hallo" you will forward to a new page with that url 
https://example.com/s/hallo

I you search for sentence it should look like 
https://example.com/s/hallo+world

I simple could say that it should be like the wordpress posts

But would be the best way (note I hate it to get a url like example.com/s?a=blabala)

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how to do the rewrites so the user can load `https://example.com/s/hallo` and the server populates `$_GET['a']`? Is that right? If so look at `pretty urls`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Comment: @chris85 thank you for your reply I know it is possible with htaccess to get url pretty, but how it is possible to save it so that every search value have is own page like a wordpress post  page

Comment: Every page doesn't have it's own page per say. You'll have a global loader, so whatever `/s` loaded before still loads but just search the GET parameter. It will look like pages to users/bots but is actually just one page.